# Why do I get specified cast is not valid while handling double?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, double

Reading from a Microsoft SQL database where I have a column with just decimal value and no nulls I get the "specified cast is not valid" while trying to group the data.
It's complaining on the "Tid" row.

(Using sql server 2008)

```
var resultat = (from row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                        let ansvarig = row.Field<string>("Ansvarig")
                        let namn = row.Field<string>("Namn")
                        let vecka = row.Field<int>("Vecka")
                        let tid = row.Field<double>("Tid")
                        group row by new { ansvarig, namn, vecka } into grp
                        select new
                        {
                            Ansvarig = grp.Key.ansvarig,
                            Namn = grp.Key.namn,
                            Vecka = grp.Key.vecka,
                            Total = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Tid"))
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried other datatypes, such as `decimal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type is `decimal` in SQL Server then it should map to [`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .Net, try:

```
row.Field<decimal>("Tid") //instead of double
```

If the column has no `null` value but it has `Allow null` set to true, then you need `Nullable<decimal>` or `decimal?`

See: [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)